# File Dialog: different behaviour for browsing back and forth

Tags: gnome, filemanager, dialog

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and the gnome shell. My default file manager is nemo, but nautilus is also installed.

My problem is that some applications do not support browsing to the parent directory with the "backspace" key in the file dialog. I believe that this affects mainly all the GNOME applications (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps).

Examples for applications with no support: Gedit, Evince, Baobab, Brasero, EOG, File Roller, Shotwell.

This is very annoying when focussing on using the keyboard only to browse files.
Are there different applications called for the file dialog? Or is it due to application-specific settings?

Thanks in advance